# Excel Forumula vlookup

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

I have a set of values in Column E, and a set of values in Column F. I would like a vlookup in Column I to match the value of E to the same value in column F, and then fill I with whatever is to the right of the matched value in F.

any help is appreciated! I believe is needed but I can't seem to grasp them

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this (start in `I1`) :

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(E1;F:F;1;0);"")
```

`IFERROR` leave blank cell if `VLOOKUP` doesn't match